# CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am trying to make rounded corners in IE with the [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) attached behavior.

Here is my CSS:

```
.fieldRow {
    clear:both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height:17px;
}
.alternate, .rowMousedOver {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(PIE.php);
    position: relative;
}
.rowMousedOver{
    background-color: #E2E66D !important;
}
.alternate {
    background-color: #FCFEE8;
}
```

and here is some sample HTML:

```
<div class="fieldRow alternate">
                <div class="label"><label id="title_label" for="title"> Title: </label></div>
                <div class="fieldWrapper required text">
                    <div class="cellValue"><input type="text" onchange="validateField(this)" name="title" id="title" value="Tax Free Savings Accounts" disabled=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and via javascript I add `rowMousedOver` to the `fieldRow` when it is hovered.

Any idea as to why this is not working? I've also tried using `behavior: url(PIE.htc)`, but had no luck with that either.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work on Firefox and chrome?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the path. Because htc is a MS standard, the url path is relative to the document rather than the stylesheet. You can always try using an absolute URL first.

Comment: That is what cordesmj also suggested, but I've put it in the right spot and it is still not rounding.

Comment: z-index doesn't work on relative position... only on absolute ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The PIE.htc requests should respond with the mime type "text/x-component" - or IE won't touch the behaviour. The PIE.php you use should fix this. If you are not sure if this is the case, use FireBug's Net feature to check a direct request to the file.

Also note that the path to PIE.htc is relative TO THE HTML PAGE - not relative to the css file which you would expect. So consider making the path to the .htc absolute. Here FireBug can help you again to detect if you have a 404 issue.

More info at http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Comment: i don't see a request for PIE.php, but i put both PIE.php and PIE.htc in the same directory as the PHP file that is running. what could the problem be?

Comment: it works now, but i'm getting a "Stack Overflow in Line 0" =S when i take out the css for PIE, i stop getting that error. any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, i see that if you apply it to the same element twice (with two different classes) it causes that stack overflow. i'll limit to one :) thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 12):

Try adding a `position: relative` into you css statement.  I've had that issue a couple of times and it's normally resolved by doing that.  Further information can be found at: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Comment: I've added that to the CSS, but still no rounding =S

Comment: Take a peek at http://www.simnom.co.uk/pie.  This has the rounded corners on the box using the PIE.php as the included behaviour file.

Comment: Just add this is working in IE8 with compatiblity mode on and off.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding

```
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
```

as suggested here http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in your path, depending on where you put the PIE.htc file. Note that Pie's 'getting started' documentation ([here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)) mentions the following:

> ...you will need to adjust the path to match where you uploaded PIE.htc in step 2. *Note: this path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.*

So `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` should work if the PIE.htc file is in the same folder as your html file (at least, it worked for me :-) ).

However, not sure what you want to see rounded... the div that would be affected doesn't seem to have any visible features. If you want to see the div with rounded corners, you might want to make the border or background visible, such as adding `border: 1px solid black;` or `background-color: someColor;` to the fieldrow class.

If you want to see the input field rounded, you might want to declare the class as `.fieldRow input {...}`

Comment: I just did as you said, as I had the two files where my CSS is located, but not in the root folder, where all the pages are, but it still does not work (tried both PIE.htc and PIE.php).

Comment: The !important declaration seems to be messing things up a bit... if I remove that, though, the code seems to work. Also, position: relative; didn't seem to be necessary. What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Neophyte's answer here (to use a conditional comment in the head section) helped me out when everything else seemed fine / did not make a difference (on the simplest of test pages, from IIS 7 with IE8)

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/9144.htm

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting - I had an issue where rounded corners were not working in lte IE8 when I'd set a background color with an `!important` rule after it.  Another reason not to use !important!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for me is as follows:

1. The path to PIE.htc needs to be absolute e.g. behavior: url(App_Themes/Default/PIE.htc)
2. Make sure the div that you set the behavior in has a style of Position: Relative

Dan