# curved bordered CSS for IE8

Tags: html, css, javascript, css3pie

I need curved bordered CSS for IE8 and all major browsers. currently I am trying with [CSS PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/)

jsfiddle demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bDvRd/3/). But I would suggest the answerers to download the PIE.htc file form [here](http://css3pie.com/download-latest) and try the HTML as a standalone page to get the real effect in IE8.

My problem is the `<td>` containing the "Thank you for registering" text is not curving in IE8 in jsfiddle. If I run it as a HTML page, it is curving in IE8 but the blue background is overlapping the "Thank you for registering" `<td>` (but its background is "#f2f2f2").

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 60%; text-align: center;background: #0067C8;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height: 50px; background-color: #262626; width:100%; text-align: left;">
                            <img src="twitter_logo.png" width="200" height="50" alt"Twitter" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height: 25px;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:3%;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="width: 94%; background-color: #f2f2f2; height: 400px; font-family: arial; font-size: 30px; color: #2DB8ED; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #bcbcbc;text-align: center;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px; behavior: url(PIE.htc);">
                            Thank you for registering
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:3%;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height: 25px;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its mainly because of Problems with z-index.

Check here for more details. [general issues encountered when using PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/)

Comment: you rock @Exor ! found it ! `position:relative;z-index: 0;` in the outer <td> (with background color) did the trick !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/ jquery plugin to add curves?

```
$(function () {
   $('table table tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').corner();
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bDvRd/4/

Comment: I am not using jQuery with that stand-alone page, it is an email-template actually. But +1 as you are correct. I need a CSS-based solution. could you please try once ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no CSS solution which will work on all the major browsers. It would be harsh to say that either go with a JS solution or do not consider such browsers not supporting corners.

Answer (score 1):

Try add

```
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
```

by [Using CSS3Pie htc for border-radius in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326363/using-css3pie-htc-for-border-radius-in-ie8)

OR [CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522145/css3-pie-giving-ie-border-radius-support-not-working/)

Comment: +1 for being correct ! but I have already accepted a similar answer :)