# Does not work border-radius IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

To implement the border-radius in IE8 I use **border-radius.htc**

The block in which to work correctly realzovat border-radius:

```
.mc-button
{
    -moz-transition: all 0.218s ease 0s;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #CBCBCB, #DCDCDC);
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 29px;
    min-width: 70px;
    padding: 0 8px !important;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-outline-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif !important;
    behavior:url(Content/border-radius.htc);
}
```

According to the list of attached files - **border-radius.htc** connects to the page

Can you please tell how to solve the problem?

**UPDATE (06/13/2012)**

If the code is replaced by a button:

```
.mc-button
{
    border: 1px solid #696;
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 29px;
    min-width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 8px !important;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #00ADEE;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#00ADEE), to(#0078A5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    behavior: url("Content/PIE.htc");
}
```

and to declare as:

```
<a id="login_button" class="mc-button mc-button-submit ">SomeText</a>

.mc-button-submit
{
    border: 0px solid #0076A3;
    background: #00ADEE;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#00ADEE), to(#0078A5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    background: linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#00ADEE, #0078A5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Rounding it disappears. Adding to the **.mc-button-submit** line **behavior: url ("Content / PIE.htc");** does not help.

Can you please tell how to connect a second class with the parameters of the background?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the .htc file?

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is not installed, just connect using: behavior:url(border-radius.htc);

Comment: Use [css3please.com](http://css3please.com/) for right and crossbrowser syntax of css3 features and [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for making crossbrowser gradients

Comment: I improved your styles and provide example which should work

Comment: Did any answer below fix your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standalone **.htc** hack is not working for background `gradient` and `border-radius` both at the same time.

Try to replace css `gradient` with simple image. This trick will work.

Also you can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) (thanks to @dop-trois) — this pure Javascript tool is more perfect than standalone `.htc` file.

**PS.** Inset `box-shadow`s cannot be implemented in both solutions.

**PPS:** the code you need is here: (i changed it a bit to make it more valid and correct):

```
.mc-button {
    font: bold 11px/29px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;

    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    height: 29px;
    min-width: 70px;
    padding: 0 8px !important;
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;

    float: left;

    /* Unique link for this gradient — http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#cbcbcb+0,dcdcdc+100;Custom */
    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(203,203,203,1) 0%, rgba(220,220,220,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(203,203,203,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(220,220,220,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(203,203,203,1) 0%,rgba(220,220,220,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(203,203,203,1) 0%,rgba(220,220,220,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(203,203,203,1) 0%,rgba(220,220,220,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(203,203,203,1) 0%,rgba(220,220,220,1) 100%); /* W3C */

    /* css3 stuff below: (via css3please.com) */
    /* no one prefix except `-webkit` is needed nowadays for `border-radius` */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.218s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.218s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.218s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.218s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.218s ease-out;

    /* PIE specific accordingly http://css3pie.com/documentation/q-and-a/ */
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

#### You should be sure that you have included `PIE.htc` correctly (important!)

#### Relative questions

- [Using CSS3Pie htc for border-radius in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326363/using-css3pie-htc-for-border-radius-in-ie8)
- [CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522145/css3-pie-giving-ie-border-radius-support-not-working/)
- [CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522145/css3-pie-giving-ie-border-radius-support-not-working/)

Accordingly to answers possible problems may be in mime type ("text/x-component").

Also possible solution may be:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Comment: In IE9 after removing and adding a gradient black background - there is a second block with rounded corners and then the background propaadet. In IE8 - a block once the background is not visible

Comment: Previously, I could not answer. Thank you for the example. I hooked PIE.htc file to the project. With F12 -> Network has verified that the file is connected correctly. Replaced by your own code - the corners are not rounded.

Comment: @SomeName Can I see your example?

Comment: Deleted the additional classes, which was a gradient of a button - it worked, thank you)

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov The only, look, please, the update in first post)

Comment: I made haste, did not notice that browsing mode IE9. The above code in the first post in the Update does not work for .mc-button for IE8.

Comment: I found some another solutions and answered questions for you, try it.

Comment: Excellent. Works) Thank you) The only. On the main page - all the buttons are displayed correctly rounded and gradient. When you go to other pages that use a similar button in IE8 - styles disappear and buttons are square and without a gradient. in IE9 - styles disappear and buttons are rounded, but without a gradient. When checking F12 -> Network File not in the list attached files

Comment: Still, I connect with PIE.htc behavior: url ("Content / PIE.htc"); within the class definition. Maybe I need to connect something else because I connect this file in several classes?

Comment: Thanks dear you gave me exact solution. I was troubling from 2 days. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 2):

To apply gradients and border-radius, I recommend **[CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/)**. It's the **most powerful tool** i know, to apply CSS3 properties in IEs.

#### Apply gradients in IEs):

```
#myElement {
    background: #CCC; /*fallback for non-CSS3 browsers*/
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#CCC) to(#EEE)); /*old webkit*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*new webkit*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*gecko*/
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*IE10*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*opera 11.10+*/
    background: linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*future CSS3 browsers*/
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*PIE*/
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}​
```

#### Apply border-radius in IEs):

```
#myAwesomeElement {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
}​
```

You'll need PHP to get it work.

**[Live demo](http://css3pie.com/)** on CSS3 Pie's website.

Btw.: Applying border-radius & gradients the same time is possible with this tool ;)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it is possible only for PIE and not standalone `.htc`

Comment: Correct, like i pointed in my answer "You'll need PHP to get it work."

Comment: Thanks, but PHP is not used on the project.

Comment: .HTC files is pure javascript files, and not require PHP support

Comment: Sorry for that, I just realized that no php tags set in this question. @Vladimir Starkov: I know,- strange, CSS3 Pie has PHP-Files inside, and I remember, I had to put these on server to get it work..

Comment: @dop-trois php files included in PIE only if you'd like prefer preprocess your `css` on the server

Comment: @VladimirStarkov: Thanks for that information :), so your answer seems the best workaround.

Comment: @dop-trois i updated my answer with actual information and mentioned your investigations of problem

Answer (score 0):

To apply Gradients, Box shadows and Border-radius, I recommend CSS3 Pie. I used it in cook&smile project and it fully works in IE.

```
*{ behavior:url(path/PIE.htc);}

.border_radius_div{ position:relative; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px;  border-radius: 10px;}

.gradient_div{ position:relative; 
background: #EEFF99;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); }
```

Visit this website to explore yourself further.

[http://css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com/)

Note:

1. Don't forget to use position (relative or absolute) where we are using Border-radius, gradients and box shadows.
2. Don't forget to use `behavior:url(xhtml_folder/PIE.htc);`
3. And the important thing is don't forget to put the PIE.htc in xhtml folder.