# Set Border color of round corner div in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, border, rounded-corners

I am having problem to set the div border , which using the `border-radius.htc`.

It works in all browsers except `IE`.

I referred this site to make a `div` as rounded corners http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/

My HTML will be,

```
<div id="div1">
  <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
</div>
```

CSS will be,

```
#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #D1C9CC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: red; 
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(jquery/border-radius.htc);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#txtBox {
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    border-style: none;
}
```

My need to set the `textbox` rounded corner with `border` of `red` color in the `IE`. How can I modify this ?

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Do your jquery/border-radius.htc file exist ?

Comment: If you know the exact size of your box or `div` then you could use a background image the same size as your box and apply rounded corners to that.

Comment: @dystroy Yes I am having the file.So I can make the div as rounded.

Comment: @Andrew I need to do this with Only `CSS`.

Comment: I have never heard of a `.htc` file. The only way that I know is to use this: https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/ but you need to get each user to install it into there own browser. Also a background image is part of CSS

Comment: Here is someone else that asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326363/using-css3pie-htc-for-border-radius-in-ie8

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your suggestion.But this is not possible for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29496/discussion-between-kite-player-and-andrew)

Comment: They say add this to your css: `position:relative; z-index: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to select F12 on your keyboard while inside of IE and check which document mode you are in. Anything below IE 9 will not work. [image]

Comment: What version of IE are you attempting to make sure this works for. In your project summary (depending if you have one) your client should have a preference of everything should work in IE7 or IE8. If so, I can help you but I need to know how far back in versions you want to go. This may be one of those situations where using javascript and Browser version detection is necessary.

Comment: My client needs the support in IE6/IE7/IE8+ and all other browsers.

Comment: In that case you will need to script this by either using CSS and or Images. IMO dont use tables, use divs, and your gonna need 2 css versions, one for 8 - 7 and one just for IE9 (which will be your easier one).

Comment: IE 8-7 if you code it correctly (not implying you wont) IE6 should work without any issues. The IE9 just use webkit and border radius, you can also use LESS, do some research on CSS LESS this is a perfect example of a site that would possibly benefit from it.