# CSS3PIE - Border-Radius Not working on <button>s in IE7/8

Tags: css, css3pie

CSS3PIE works for all other elements on my site from `<div>`s to `<img>`s but I cannot for the life of me get it to work on `<button>` elements.

I've tried some usual hacks to get things to work like so (I'm using SASS):

```
button {
    position: relative !important;
    zoom: 1 !important;
    display: block !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    -ms-behavior: url(/assets/pie/PIE.htc) !important;
    behavior: url(/assets/pie/PIE.htc) !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Whatever I try, the `border-radius` just does nothing.

Changing them from `<buttons>` to other html elements is not an option.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CSS3Pie htc for border-radius in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326363/using-css3pie-htc-for-border-radius-in-ie8)

Comment: I had already read that but the answer did not work therefore I need a new answer - You can see in my question that I have already tried the answer IN that post that you suggested.

Comment: A workaround is wrap the  `input button` inside the div and then give border-radius to the div. And remove border from `button`.

Comment: Thanks Kheema I'll do that