# CSS3 and PIE not working in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, css3pie

Im trying to demo CSS3PIE and it wont work in IE at all.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <link href="test.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="sub_title"></div>
    <div id="main_area">
      <div id="date_area"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#title{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: white;
}

#sub_title{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}

#date_area{
  width: 310px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #4A4949;
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #707070 2px 2px 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #707070 2px 2px 4px;
  box-shadow: #707070 2px 2px 4px;
  background: #EBEBEB;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EDEBEB), to(#C9C7C8));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EDEBEB, #C9C7C8);
  background: linear-gradient(#EDEBEB, #C9C7C8);
  -pie-background: linear-gradient(#EDEBEB, #C9C7C8);
  behavior: url(/PIE.htc);  
}
```

The result is just a block with a border, no gradient/shadow etc

Any help/solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason to not using `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#EDEBEB', endColorstr='#C9C7C8',GradientType=0 );`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `behavior` location should be relative to your HTML file, not your CSS like any other declaration using `url()`. So assuming your `index.html` and `PIE.htc` is in root and your CSS is inside a 'css' folder, you should go like this:

```
background-image: url(../images/example.jpg);
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

Also, try adding a `.htaccess` file with the following content in the same location as the `PIE.htc` file:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That fixed it in IE10 for IE8 compatibility mode, but not in the real IE8...any ideas?

Comment: @DrCord wow, didn't knew that... Not sure of that since i'm currently not relying on CSS3PIE anymore. I'm supporting IE8+ and i code a solid layout structure; regarding "fancy visual effects": what works on IE, works on IE, and what doesn't, no big deal, design looks good anyways.

Answer (score 14):

Try adding

```
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
```

as suggested here http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10

This question is similar to the one posted here: [CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522145/css3-pie-giving-ie-border-radius-support-not-working/)

Comment: ^ this guy is a life saver !

Comment: for me, adding z-index:0 removed the text inside the element. however, adding just position:relative really helped

Answer (score 4):

[CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522145/css3-pie-giving-ie-border-radius-support-not-working)

> The PIE.htc requests should respond with the mime type "text/x-component" - or IE won't touch the behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

adding: `AddType text/x-component .htc`  - to the `.htaccess` file worked like a charm for me.

The shorthand CSS property let's you control what corners to round or not.

`border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;/*(top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left). */`

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear cache in your browser. Especialy when you switch between compatibility modes. It really helps

Comment: This should be as comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest beta release. If the HTC file still causes issues, try the JS implementation.