# CSS rounded corners in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

I'm having issues with rounded corners in IE8. I've tried a few methods without success.

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #505050;
  line-height: normal;
}
p {
  margin: 4px;
}
.categoryheading3 {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #297BB6;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
.leftcolumn {
  width: 174px;
  padding: 8px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  /*--min-height: 500px*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
.lefttop {
  display: inline-block;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0 5px 2em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #297BB6;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="leftcolumn">
  <div class="lefttop">
    <H4 class="categoryheading3">Heading</H4>
    <p>sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which produces this in Firefox:

[image: firefox example]

But this in IE8:

[image: IE8 makes me sad]

If anyone has any tips I'd be very grateful!

edit: Joseph helped by suggesting to use pie.htc, however I'm still struggling with this element not working:

```
.categoryheading3 {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  background-color: #297BB6;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: it looks to me like your css is missing the standard border-radius property

Comment: Your IE8 screenshot actually looks Metro UI ish :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Internet Explorer (under version 9) does not natively support rounded corners.

There's an amazing script that will magically add it for you: [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

I've used it a lot of times, with amazing results.

Comment: This works well for the element which is round on all corners, however I can't seem to get it to work on the one which only has rounded top left+right - any suggestions?

Comment: @kevyn: Can you show me the CSS you're using? CSS3 PIE supports only shorthand properties (`border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;`), not the longhand ones (`border-radius-topleft: 5px; etc.`).

Comment: I edited my CSS which is in the OP, and I added behavior: url(PIE.htc); into both elements. The element with 4 rounded corners works well, but the one with only the top 2 corners doesn't make any difference

Comment: I've updated my post to include the CSS which I can't get to work (I tried your suggestion of using shorthand format)

Comment: You're only using the vendor-prefixed versions. CSS3 PIE works with the standard one: `border-radius`.

Comment: Great concept, pathetic execution. It fixes 3 parts of your CSS and messes up all the rest.

Comment: PIE renders properly the corners, for example border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;, but it makes my div opaque. I am using opacity: .6; and filter: alpha(opacity=60);

Comment: PIE fixed the rounded corners for me but somehow stopped a background colors working, so it seems to be hit and miss

Answer (score 33):

## [Rounded corners in IE8](http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners)

Internet Explorer 8 (and earlier versions) **doesn't** support rounded corners, **however** there are **few other solutions you may consider:**

- Use Rounded Corners `Images` instead ([**this**](http://www.generateit.net/rounded-corner/) generator is a good resource)
- Use a `jQuery Corner plugin` from [**here**](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner)
- Use a very good script called `CSS3 PIE` from **[here](http://css3pie.com)** (Pro's & Con's [here](http://css-plus.com/2011/05/ie-and-rounded-corners/))
- Checkout `CSS Juice` from [**here**](http://www.cssjuice.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/)
- Another good script is `IE-CSS3` from **[here](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)**

Even though CSS PIE is the most popular solution, I suggest you review all other solutions and choose what works best for your needs.

I hope it was useful. Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

I didnt know about css3pie.com, a very useful site after seeing this post:

But what after testing it out it didnt work for me either.  However I found that wrapping it in the .PHP file worked fine.  So instead of:

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

use this:

```
behavior: url(PIE.php);
```

I put mine in a folder called jquery, so mine was:

```
 behavior: url(jquery/PIE.php);
```

So goto their downloads or get it here:

http://css3pie.com/download-latest

And use their PHP file.  Inside the PHP file it explains that some servers are not configured for proper .HTC usage.  And that was the problem I had.

Try it! I did, it works.  Hope this helps others out too.

Comment: unfortunately this still didn't do anything for me on IE8 :(

Comment: This is because you haven't configured the correct MIME type on the webserver for .htc files. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4672959/229587

Answer (score 2):

http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ works for IE 6+. Use this if css3pie doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

PIE.htc worked for me great (http://css3pie.com/), but with one issue:

You should write absolute path to PIE.htc. It hasn't worked for me when I used relative path.

Comment: it looks like relative pathing is not relative to the css file on this, but relative to the docroot instead

Comment: ph33nyx is almost correct. When using Internet Explorer behaviors, the document being referenced is relative to the calling HTML file, not the CSS file. Just be aware of this when you use it so you don't go crazy trying to find out why it isn't working.

Comment: I am using it with relative path as `behavior: url(../PIE/PIE.htc);` and it's working fine.

Comment: levgen you don't know how much I am thankful thank you!!! you were right relative path didn't worked and I studied whole the pie forums and I was just hopeless but I used the complete path and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

As Internet Explorer doesn't natively support rounded corners. 
So a better cross-browser way to handle it would be to use rounded-corner images at the corners. Many famous websites use this approach.

You can also find rounded image generators around the web. One such link is http://www.generateit.net/rounded-corner/

Comment: thats a very old approach, I wouldnt reccommend this. Libs like PIE made css3 possible in ie8 and is all we need.