# CSS rounded corners IE8 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css

is it possible to have rounded corners in IE8 and 7?

Here is my code below:

```
#box{
        background-color:#000;
        color:#FFF;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-weight:bold;
        height:50px;
        border-radius:10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
        font-size:16px;
}
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rounded corners in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077331/css-rounded-corners-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

Not with border-radius, you will need to use images

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 Pie (http://css3pie.com/) - it's a javascript library that recreates some of the CSS3 features in IE6-9, including border-radius.