# CSS3 PIE not showing rounded corners in IE8 mode within IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11, css3pie, ie11-developer-tools

I'm not getting rounded corners in IE8 mode within IE11.
I've tried both relative and absolute paths, and neither work.
The PIE.htc file is in the same folder as the html file. I'm running on Jetty and don't have a .htaccess file. The PIE.htc file can be loaded without any problem using `http://localhost:8383/various_forms2_less/PIE.htc`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style>
            span.command_link_buttoned {
                background-color: #96AFCF;
                display: block;
                width: 130px;
                height:30px;
                position:relative;
                border-radius: 5px;
                behavior: url(PIE.htc);
                /*behavior: url(http://localhost:8383/various_forms2_less/PIE.htc);*/
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="command_link_buttoned">
            Button
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most probably IE 11 won't process htc file. Why do you even interested in IE 11 @ IE 8 mode?

Comment: Possbile duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077331/css-rounded-corners-in-ie8