# How to create rounded corner buttons in ie 8

Tags: css

I want to show round corner buttons in Internet Explorer 9 but this was worked in all other browsers except Internet Explorer 9. `Border-radius:20px;`

Comment: See: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077331/css-rounded-corners-in-ie8)

Comment: this is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie